# CSS- Targeting multiple images inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to add individual borders to each image inside of a div. Currently I have a border around the entire section that holds the photos, but I'm trying to get the actual image itself.

Below is an example of the html

```
<div id="options">
 <img id="rock" src="rock.jpg" name="rock" width="265" height="250" />

 <img id="paper" src="paper.jpg" name="paper" width="265" height="250" />
 <img id="scissors" src="scissors.jpg" name="scissors" width="265" height="250" />
 <img id="lizard" src="lizard.jpg" name="lizard" width="265" height="250" />
 <img id="spock" src="spock.jpg" alt="spock" width="265" height="250" />

<div id="compPick">
 <img id="blank" src="blankpic.jpg" name="blank" width="265" height="250" />
</div>
 //div below ends the option div
</div>
```

below is my current css

```
 #options{
text-align: center; 
border: 2px solid #333333;
background-color: #D0CECE;
display: block;
 }

 #compPick{
text-align: center; 
border: 2px solid #333333;
padding: 5px;
 }
```

`compPick` is a blank image that changes depending on a randomly generated number/choice. I'd like to keep the border around the sections, but I also would like the border around the images themselves.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
#options img {
    border: 2px solid #333333;
}
```

The `img` selects all `<img>` tags.

---

**Explanation:** When you add a space between selectors, it means "descendant of". For example, with this HTML:

```
<div class="awesome">
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">text 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar">text 2</div>
</div>

<div class="bar">text 3</div>
```

if you use this selector in CSS:

```
.awesome .bar { /* styles here */ }
```

it will select both the `div` with `text 1` and the `div` with `text 2` but it does not select the `div` with `text 3` since that `div` is not a descendant of an element with class `awesome`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this CSS:**

```
.div img {
  margin: 0 1vmax;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

The img selects all `<img>` tags.

**Explanation:** When you add a space between selectors, it means "descendant of".